# update only records with a max value using group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, having-clause

I have some data, and wherever the server_id, product_id, and polled_at date match, i want to set updated_by to 2 (only searching rows where updated by is already 1). I have been messing with my code for a while, but can't figure it out. Please help me. here is what I have.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebd112/1

The first 2 rows should not get updated, and only the max peak between all other rows where the server_id, product_id, and polled_at match up, should be updated to updated_by=2

Thanks

Comment: So you are only wanting to update the records where `licenses_peak = 30` in this scenario?

Comment: I want to only update records where updated_by=1, and set it to 2 if the duplicate record has the greatest peak

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a HAVING clause to your query.  Here is the updated fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e3a9/1

Basically, rather than trying to sort it as you were initially doing, I changed the `ORDER BY` into a `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING licenses_peak = (SELECT Max(licenses_peak) FROM hpolls WHERE updated_by=1)
```

This will cause the query to only include those items that have the maximum `licenses_peak` value for that grouping.

Comment: that is not what I need. I want to update all records (except where updated_by=0), and only set updated_by to 2 if the duplicate where server_id, and prouduct_id, and polled_at has a greater peak.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding your question.  That fiddle that I posted does exactly that.. which items in your list should it be updating?

Comment: I got it working using this: UPDATE hpolls set updated_by=2 where id in (
SELECT id FROM (select * from hpolls where updated_by=1 order by licenses_peak desc) as sub
    GROUP BY server_id, product_id, polled_at);

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would work, unless you made it `SELECT TOP 1 id FROM ...` otherwise it will still be updating all of your records that have `updated_by=1`.  Just ordering by licenses_peak descending doesn't do anything by itself, you have to specify how many records you want the query to return, in this case the subquery.